# More than one function on scroll?

Tags: javascript

With my current code I can only have one or the other, which is either my sticky navigation or a back to top button that appears at a 100px from the top of the document. Is there any way I can use both?

This is my current code

```
window.onscroll = function() {navFunction()};
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
function navFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
```

and

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
    }
}
function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
}
```

sorry if this is a silly question. I am still new to this :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can call both functions inside `window.onscroll` anonymous function:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    navFunction();
    scrollFunction();
};
```

Alternatively, you can use the standard `addEventListener` method to register both functions:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", navFunction);
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollFunction);
```

Notice that in this way we don't use the parentheses with the two functions because we're not executing them. We're just telling the event listener the name of the function that it will execute when the event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is just reorganize your code to call both functions.

```
// Define the functions and the variables you need first here
// function topFunction() {...}  etc

// call both functions inside the scroll event here.
window.onscroll = function() {
    scrollFunction();
    navFunction()
};
```

The other way to run multiple functions on an event is by using `addEventListener()`

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",scrollFunction,false);
window.addEventListener("scroll",navFunction,false);
```

You can keep appending as many functions as you want, though you risk making your web page slower.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onscroll = function() {onscroll_function()};
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
function onscroll_function() {
   navFunction();
   scrollFunction();
   //...what ever else you want to trigger
}

function navFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
    }
}
function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
}
```